# Enhanced Rich Text Field removes my default text

Tags: jquery, form, default-value

Im trying to set default text using jquery on a mentioned field type. I can briefly see my text as I open a new form, but then it disappears. I tried various methods - .text() .html() .append() but i get the same result. How can I set that field?

```
$(".ms-rtestate-write").html("lots of text");
$(".ms-rtestate-write").append("<p>Test</p>");
```

Comment: On which page are you trying to do this?

Comment: It's not working in Sharepoint 2016 list multiple lines of text feild (Enhanced rich text ),how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well every other method still didn't work. SharePoint just wipes the text when the form loads. So I created a button which adds the default text when user clicks it.

```
var templateText = "teeeeeext";
$(".ms-rtestate-write").parent().parent().append("<input id=\"templateLink\" type=\"button\" value=\"Incident Template\">");
$(".ms-rtestate-write").html(templateText);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('nobr:contains("your multiple line text field name")').closest('tr').find('div.ms-rtestate-write').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var systemDescriptionRTETextArea = $("textarea[Title='System Description']");
$(systemDescriptionRTETextArea).html("paste your text here");
```

**OR**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {    

    $('nobr:contains("Desc")').closest('tr').find('input[id$="TextField_spSave"]').val('Hello World !!!');
    });
```

**OR**

```
$('nobr:contains("Rich Text")').closest('tr').find('input[id$="TextField_spSave"]').

val('<table border="1"><tr><td>Hello </td><td><b>World !!!</b></td></tr></table>');
```

try and give your feedback.